# Stripping a middle initial with a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I know I'm doing something stupid here, but I'm tired and I'm apparently just not seeing it. I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names = (
    "John Q. Public",
    "James K Polk"
);

foreach (@names)
{
    print "Before: $_\n";
    s/\b[A-Z]\.?\b//;
    print "After:  $_\n";
}
```

When I run this script, I get the following output:

```
Before: John Q. Public
After:  John . Public      <== Why is the period still here?
Before: James K Polk
After:  James  Polk
```

Note that in the *John Q. Public* example, the period is left. Isn't the optional match argument (`?`) greedy? According to [the perlre docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> ? Match 1 or 0 times

Shouldn't the period disappear along with the middle initial? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is

```
". " =~ /\.\b/ or print "There is no word boundary between a dot and a space.\n"
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for help; as soon as I can accept the answer, I will.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would choose to split the name on whitespace and select just the first and last fields.

Like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names = ("John Q. Public", "James K Polk");

foreach (@names) {
  print "Before: $_\n";
  $_ = join ' ', (split)[0, -1];
  print "After:  $_\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Before: John Q. Public
After:  John Public
Before: James K Polk
After:  James Polk
```